# How can the gcd(a,b), t, be written as a linear combination t=la +kb for some integers?

Tags: integers

In Pinter's book it states that the greatest common divisor of a and b can be written as the linear combination:

$t=la + kb $ for some integers $l$ and $b$

What is the proof of this?

Comment: Look up the "Euclidean Algorithm"

Comment: Look up the "Extended Euclidean Algorithm"

Comment: I see how that works but how does it relate to this?

Answer (score 0):

This is standard bookwork. Take the smallest positive $la+kb$ for integers $l,k$. Call it $d$. Suppose it does not divide $a$. Then we have $a=qd+r$ with $0<r<d$, but $r$ is a linear combination of $a,b$. Contradiction. Similarly $d$ must divide $b$ and hence $t$. But $t$ obviously divides $d$, so they are equal.

Comment: What do you mean smallest possible integers? 0?

Comment: Sorry I meant positive. Autocorrect

Comment: Also if l and k are positive won't t be bigger than a and b? How can the common divisor be bigger that either a or b?

Comment: Where did I say they were positive? Indeed you have just established that only one of $k,l$ will be positive!

Comment: Ah you were talking about the whole sum being positive

Comment: Okay so how is r being a linear combination a contradiction?